# How to install packages before given date with zypper?

Tags: zypper

We cannot find the parameter for it in the man pages, but maybe there is a solution for it:

**Question**: How can we install packages before a given date? So not the up-to-date version of a package, but an older one that was issued before a given date.

Selecting them one-by-one by hand is too slow.

Comment: Can you paste sample output of a zypper command that provides the option of selecting an older version of a package?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll be able to install before a given date. I tried setting the system date backwards and that doesn't work. Nor is there an option you can pass to rpm which is what zypper uses underneath.

So the only approach I can think of is to set up a local RPM repository for SuSe, and fill that with those packages before a certain date and use that. To find out what was available at a certain date [archive.org](http://download.opensuse.org/) may be useful.

See [this](http://vavai.net/2008/10/making-a-local-copy-of-opensuse-repository-mirror-server/) for how to set up a local OpenSuSE repository.

Comment: +1 I was going to write this up, but got sidetracked.  Do you mind including instructions for setting up a local repository?

Comment: I would, but I have never set up a local RPM repository for SuSE, so all I'd be doing is copying or paraphrasing the instructions given in the link with the possibility of adding noise to the instructions.

Comment: That was the point of me asking... You don't realize how many Google visitors we get coming from a dead link on "How To ... (install a local rpm)", so if we follow a link that isn't dead and paraphrase it before the link dies, readers will just have to look here... plus i can guarantee more upvotes, albeit slowly, as all the other links go dead.

Comment: A couple of things. If this question were "How to set up a SuSE Remote Repository" then that would make a lot of sense. But it's a proposed solution to a different problem; right now we don't even know if it is the best solution. Yes,  it sucks when links outside of SO go bad, but for a topic like this, information can also be stale and may change as SuSE does.. There are 3 alternatives I see here. Post another question (best idea) and answer that, and I'll link it here. Or someone with first-hand knowledge can add a comment to this or edit my answer. Or provide another answer.

Answer (score 0):

`zypper search -s --match-substrings` may be the best search option you can have. However, it doesn't really search package build date in the RPM.  I think what you try to do is pull/install all updates released before certain date.

What I did was manually pull packages, host them with a Repo.  My repo is on a CentOS host.  It was created with createrepo. In the zypper .repo file, specify "type=yum".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to install a specific version of package before the up-to-date one.
For example with MozillaFirefox, when searching for MozillaFirefox packages with the following command:
`zypper se -t package -s MozillaFirefox`
The output will be (i586 packages and other not related one has been truncated):

> v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 38.0.1-30.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 37.0.2-27.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 37.0.1-23.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 36.0.4-18.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 36.0-14.2   | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 35.0-9.1    | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   v | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 34.0.5-5.4  | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Update
>   i | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 33.0-2.1    | x86_64 | openSUSE-13.2-Oss   
>   i | MozillaFirefox                     | package | 33.0-2.1    | x86_64 | openSU

As we can see, MozillaFirefox version 33.0-2.1 has been installed on this system and the latest one is 38.0.1-30.1.

If you wan do not want to install the latest version, and just want to install a version up to version 36.0 then all you have to do is call `zypper in` do it for you.

The syntax is:

`zypper in 'Mozillafirefox.x86_64<36.0`

You can also install the i586 architectural package
`zypper in 'Mozillafirefox.i586<36.0`
Or you can let zypper does selection package architecture for you
`zypper in 'Mozillafirefox<36.0`

Then zypper will install version 35.0-9.1 which is closest to version 36.0.

zypper also provides support for '>, <=, >=, etc'; you can see it with `zypper help in`.

Hope this is what you are looking for and hope this help.